# texts_to_sequences return empty string after loading the tokenizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, tokenize

I'm working on a project, I've trained and saved my model as well as tokenizer

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(corpus)

# save tokenizer
import pickle
# saving
with open('english_tokenizer_test.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

total_words = len(tokenizer.word_index) +1
```

```
from keras.models import load_model

model2.save('model.h5')
```

and loading the model and the tokenizer

```
with open('../input/shyaridatasettesting/english_tokenizer_test.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)

tokenizer = Tokenizer()
max_sequence_len = 24
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('../input/model.h5')
print(model);
```

So when I'm doing tokenizer using loaded tokenizer it returns an empty string

```
token_list = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(["this is something"])[0]
```

I want to use my model and tokenizer on my website but I'm getting an empty token_list whenever I pass text in into my tokenizer?

please help me if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Is your corpus a list of lists?

Comment: its just a list of sentences in this case I've around 3000 sentences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are creating a new `Tokenizer` with the same name after loading your original tokenizer and therefore it is overwritten. Here is a working example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle

corpus = ['this is something', 'this is something more', 'this is nothing']
tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(corpus)

### Save tokenizer
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    
### Load tokenizer
with open('/content/tokenizer.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)
token_list = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(["this is something"])[0]
print(token_list)
```

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Suppose I want to use my model and tokenizer on some web project outside my python file...
So I'm saving my model and tokenizer then I'm loading it outside other than the same files I used for training... So tokenizer still giving the same empty result?

Comment: No, not yet, 

Do I need to use fit_on_texts every time I load my tokenizer?

Comment: No, the tokenizer should have the same state as before saving. Is that not the case? You should only call `fit_on_texts` once.

Comment: yes, that is the problem when I'm loading my tokenizer outside the python file it's not working? just resulting empty string

Comment: Did you try the example in my answer? Save the tokenizer in one file and load it in another file. It will work, I just tested it.

Comment: Ok, i got the answer now the problem is I'm initializing a new tokenizer every time...
Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes that is what I said in the beginning of my answer: "The problem is you are creating a new Tokenizer with the same name after loading your original tokenizer and therefore it is overwritten"